# ESRI: How does one obtain circular image layers over main layer without background boxes appearing white via hatching?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp

Is their a way in ESRI using ArcInfo to create circular images on top of the primary "map" without the surrounding white boxes that the microsoft print software insists on making? I've been told hatching in GIMP or Photoshop can yet I'm not very familiar with either.

Comment: Does "ESRI" handle transparency in images?